# Symfony 3 | JMSi18nRoutingBundle doesn't translate routes

Tags: routes, translation, symfony-3.2

Guys I was using BeSimplei18nRoutingBundle but using some JMS bundles too, so I wanted all to be JMS bundles and changed it to JMSi18nRoutingBundle. Now my locale based routing working perfectly, but I cannot translate them. Looked everywhere and cannot create/find a solution.

First, I installed JMS's routing and translation bundles. Added to AppKernel.

After that, added routing configuration to config.yml file:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: tr
    locales: [tr, en]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Then, added 2 routes to routing.yml file:

```
homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
    options: { i18n: true }

secondpage:
    path:     /ikincisayfa
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:secondPage }
    options: { i18n: true }
```

After that I extracted translation file for **en** locale on console:

```
php bin/console translation:extract en --bundle=AppBundle --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --output-format=yml --exclude-dir=cache --exclude-dir=data --exclude-dir=logs --exclude-dir=Tests --exclude-dir=Service --output-dir="app/Resources/translations"
```

And translated **ikincisayfa** to **secondpage**:

```
# Desc: /
homepage: /

# Desc: /ikincisayfa
secondpage: /secondpage
```

But when I run php **bin/console debug:router** here is the output; no translation happened:

```
  tr__RG__homepage           ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                  
  en__RG__homepage           ANY      ANY      ANY    /en/                               
  tr__RG__secondpage         ANY      ANY      ANY    /ikincisayfa                       
  en__RG__secondpage         ANY      ANY      ANY    /en/ikincisayfa
```

Tried to clear cache, re-extract translations but no luck.. Can someone say where I am doing the fault please.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem.. I wasn't deleted the created-by-symfony routing in routing.yml file:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

It seems, this caused a conflict between Symfony's routing and JMS' router. I wish JMS' documentation had these information too.